# How to check Memory and CPU usage of AWS Batch job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch, amazon-cloudwatch

while creating a batch job, we can provide **vCPUs** and **Memory** in *Container properties*.

In cloudwatch, we can check memory and CPU usage per cluster under **Elastic Container Service** per cluster.

Is there any way to check memory and CPU usage per job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be nothing which is production grade right now ( August 2019)

However, here some hints:

- implementing your own solution using gmond / ganglia
- use AWS containerInsights (enable it for your account via cmd below )

`aws ecs put-account-setting-default --name "containerInsights" --value "enabled"`

- check out what Adroll did:  http://tech.adroll.com/blog/data/2018/08/08/running-jobs-with-aws-batch.html

Comment: has containerInsights worked for you? The [documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ContainerInsights.html) says "Currently, Container Insights isn't supported in AWS Batch."